# Kafka consumer receiving same message multiple times

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've recently started using kafka to read documents coming through a web crawler. What I'm noticing is when I'm dealing with few million documents, the consumer is processing the same message over and over again. Looks like the data is not getting committed for some reason. This is not the case when I'm testing the consumer with few hundred message.

I'm using kafka high level consumer client code in java. I'm using consumer group running on number of threads equivalent to number of partitions. So each thread is deciated to a partition. Here's a code snippet for polling data.

`while (true) {
    try{
        if(consumerDao.canPollTopic()){
            ConsumerRecords records = 
              consumer.poll(this.config.getPropertyAsIneger(IPreProcessorConstant.KAFKA_POLL_COUNT));
            for (ConsumerRecord record : records) {
                if(record.value()!=null){
                    TextAnalysisRequest textAnalysisObj = record.value();
                    if(textAnalysisObj!=null){
                        PostProcessRequest req = new PostProcessRequest();
                        req.setRequest(this.getRequest(textAnalysisObj));
                        PreProcessorUtil.submitPostProcessRequest(req, config);
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            Thread.sleep(this.config.getPropertyAsIneger(IPreProcessorConstant.KAFKA_POLL_SLEEP));
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        LOGGER.error("Error in Full Consumer group worker", ex);

    }
}`

Here's the kafka consumer configuration parameters I'm setting. Rest are default values.

```
consumer.auto.commit=true
consumer.auto.commit.interval=1000
consumer.session.timeout=180000
consumer.poll.records=2147483647
consumer.request.timeout=181000
```

Here's the complete consumer config:

```
metric.reporters = 
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
bootstrap.servers = [kafkahost1:9092, kafkahost2:9092]
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
enable.auto.commit = true
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
interceptor.classes = null
exclude.internal.topics = true
ssl.truststore.password = null
client.id =ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
max.poll.records = 2147483647
check.crcs = true
request.timeout.ms = 181000
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
auto.commit.interval.ms = 1000
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
fetch.min.bytes = 1
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
value.deserializer = class com.test.preprocessor.consumer.serializer.KryoObjectSerializer
group.id = full_group
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.key.password = null
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
session.timeout.ms = 180000
metrics.num.samples = 2
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.cipher.suites = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
auto.offset.reset = latest
```

My sample kafka queue is having 8 partitions with 2 replication factor.

The log retention period in server.properties is setup as 168 hours.

`log.retention.hours=168
log.roll.hours=168`

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Not sure either. However, as long as your consumers are up an running, they maintain there offset in-memory -- committing offsets is only used to preserve offsets if a consumer gets shut down or crashes. Thus, after each `poll()` the offset is advanced.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax ... Thanks. Based on the log, I can see that different threads under the consumer group are picking up the same message. Is there a possibility that the same message can be delivered to multiple partitions? I can see the offsets are getting advanced. My intention is to try to understand what can be the possible reasons behind this so that I can avoid. Are there any tweak in the configuration parameters which can avoid this ? Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: If all thread use the same `group.id`, each partition should be assigned to exactly one thread. Duplicate messages should only occur in case of rebalance (if new consumers to join or leave a group). Can you double check the partition assignment?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax .. I increased the number of partitions/consumer threads and added few million messages in the queue. Upon close introspection of the log, I found the following warning, which explained the consumer looping issue."Auto offset commit failed for group full_group: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member".I've max.poll.records=20000 and session.timeout.ms=180000ms. I guess I need to play around this for the optimal setting.Just wondering is there a best practise/thumb rule around this?

Comment: If you are sending/receiving in a synchronous manner with a 1:1 thread to partition ratio, I think it might help to set your maxInFlightConnections value to 1. The default is 5.

Answer (score 1):

I increased my `auto.commit.interval.ms=8000` in my consumer properties from `3000` to `8000`. This fixed the duplicate record issues.

Answer (score -3):

I guess the issue with the partition assignment.